# Scheme find average of a list

Tags: scheme, racket

So I have code that should find the average of a list but I see no printed value in console

```
#lang racket
(define x (list '10 '60 '3 '55 '15 '45 '40))
(define (average x)
(/ (sum x) (length x)))

(display average (current-output-port))

(define (sum)
(if (null? x)
    0
    (+ (car x) (sum (cdr x)))))
```

it simply displays

```
#<procedure:average>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has following problems:

1. `sum` was used before it was defined.
2. `sum` did not take a parameter.
3. `average` function was not evaluated in `display`.
4. I have used `exact->inexact` because that's what I think your intention is.

Following works.

```
(define x (list 10 60 3 55 15 45 40))

(define (sum x)
    (if (null? x)
        0
        (+ (car x) (sum (cdr x)))))

(define (average x)
    (/ (sum x) (length x)))

(display (exact->inexact (average x)) (current-output-port))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (average l)
  (/ (foldr (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 0 l) 
     (length l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum` and `length` are each *O(n)* resulting in a *O(2n)* process for `average`. Below we show how continuation passing style can be used to make `average` a *O(n)* process as well.

```
(define (average xs (return /))
  (if (empty? xs)
      (return 0 0)
      (average (cdr xs)
               (lambda (sum len)
                 (return (+ sum (car xs))
                         (+ len 1))))))

(printf "~a~n" (average '(10 60 3 55 15 45 40)))
;; 228/7
```

Using `exact->inexact` in `average` means only an inexact result can be returned. Making additional computations with inexact numbers leads to additional inexactitude. You might think that `inexact->exact` could reverse any of this however it can only make an approximation.

```
(average '(10 60 3 55 15 45 40)
;; 32 4/7

(inexact->exact (exact->inexact (average '(10 60 3 55 15 45 40))))
;; 32 40210710958665/70368744177664
```

For this reason it generally make sense only to convert an exact number to an inexact one just before it is displayed.

```
(printf "~a\n" (exact->inexact (average '(10 60 3 55 15 45 40))))
;; 32.57142857142857
```

Our average procedure also throws an error when an empty list is given.

```
(average '())
;; error /: division by zero
```

---

Alternatively, we could write average using a named `let` expression. Also *O(n)*.

```
(define (average xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs)
             (sum 0)
             (len 0))
    (if (empty? xs)
        (/ sum len)
        (loop (cdr xs)
              (+ sum (car xs))
              (+ len 1)))))

(average '(10 60 3 55 15 45 40)
;; 32 4/7
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be using a different version of scheme; https://scheme.cs61a.org/ is the compiler I use. It worked for me when I included the a parameter for the function `sum` like this:

```
(define (sum x)
  (if (null? x)
    0
    (+ (car x) (sum (cdr x)))))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and it returns 32.57? I put exactly whats written in but only return "average"