# Scheme function that returns avg of arguments

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a function in scheme that returns the average of its arguments. This is what I have so far. When running the code I get 6, when it should be 29/6. I am trying to do this without using recursion

```
    (define iota
  (lambda (x)
    (letrec
      ((loop
        (lambda (x acc)
(if (= x 0) acc
(loop (sub1 x) (cons x acc))))))
         (loop x '()))))

(define avg
  (lambda ls
    (let ((size (apply + (map (lambda (x) 1) ls))))
      (apply + (map (lambda (x) (apply * (iota x))) ls))
      size)))

(avg 4 5 5 5 5 5)
```

Comment: This seems a bit convoluted; what is wrong with something like `(/ (apply + ls) (length ls))`?

Comment: Where do you see the division, and why did you involve the factorial of the list elements?

Comment: And by the way: that letrec/loop part, that's an explicitly recursive procedure - so you're not meeting the goal of not using recursion.

Comment: [a duplicate. This question has been asked before and already has an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587557/scheme-find-average-of-a-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheme find average of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587557/scheme-find-average-of-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

```
(define (avg . args)
  (/ (apply + args) (length args)))
```

Test:

```
(avg 4 5 5 5 5 5)
;; => 29/6
```